# Postgresql Query timeout

Tags: postgresql, timeout, geoserver

I'm on the Geoserver platform, where one can use parametric Sql views on a database. Problem is, when the query is really long, it hangs the entire system, and it's hard for either Geoserver or Postgresql to process any more data.

Since the request is hardwired, it's hard to set a query timeout on a per session basis, as is customary. Including another command in the query is impossible, for safety reasons, so it has to be done externally.

However, I don't want the entire postgresql module to have a specific timeout(as I have already done inside the config file, setting the query timeout to 30 seconds). Is there a way to set a query timeout that only affects a specific database and not the entire server?

Comment: More than 30 seconds for a single query while many different sessions could execute it at the same time, that sound *not very optimal*. What version of PostgreSQL are you using? If 9.3 or newer, I would look into [MATERIALIZED VIEWS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rules-materializedviews.html). Also, do you have proper indexes in place and have you checked if the query is optimized?

Comment: Yes, that query is a very specific type of query that needs to be omitted. Like having a table with 500 entries, and trying to select all the entries from a join of the table to itself. 

I've tried using indexes, but the selects are really simple and don't seem to speedup anything when where clauses are missing. When where clauses are used, the queries return in a second.

I'll check the materialized views, but it seems like geoserver won't let me change anything towards that direction

Comment: If you `join` something, even a single table on itself, then indexes can be very useful. [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) is your friend when it comes to test a query's efficiency. 500 rows sounds nothing like overly complex, and if GeoServer and PostgreSQL are on the same machine, it shouldn't be a data size problem either.

Comment: It's not exactly a normal join on the tables. Like a left join. I need all the combinations between elements.

So basically, I run the following query " select c0.the_geom,c2.the_geom from "natura" c0,"natura" c2" and it runs over 30 seconds.

explain shows that the nesting leads to trouble, where "Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..60635.41 rows=175561 width=34060)"

Indexing on the ids, or the other columns doesn't seem to help, but I am not aware of show I should optimize it anyway. If it's not optimizable I just need to set a timeout for these weird queries with inefficient where clauses

Comment: It's a `CROSS JOIN` you are doing this way, not an `OUTER LEFT` one. As far as I know you can't set a single query or even session's timeout, and frankly speaking, that would be a bad idea. Why don't you try to work around the problem? Do you really need all of those combinations at once? Maybe you could try to pre-filer the geometries selecting only the ones that intersect your current viewing extent. Also, I don't think it's a DB problem, try to execute a `COUNT(*)` on that query. Probably it's GeoServer that requires a lot of time to render all those geometries.

Comment: Again, thank you for your attention to my problem. 
Generally speaking most queries fall into the "really fast" category. So If I put two boxes one inside the other and a point outside them, the sql database finds all the nested polygons really fast and just adds the points in under 4 seconds.

Most queries don't produce combinatorial explosions because most objects are unique. When there are two polygons that are symmetric in their relationships to other geometries, the sql query cannot know that, and tries to find all possible combinations. Even if I use pgadmin , the query still takes 1 min

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you then. There is no way to set *per-session* timeout.